# APEX: How to change Link column's position in interactive report?

Tags: report, oracle-apex, interactive

I want to place **Link Column** to other position, not only as first column in report. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of APEX (4.1) shows how to move column positions when you view the list of columns:
[image]

That also works in older versions, but the hint is not shown in the column attributes panel.

However, that doesn't work for the special Link Column that APEX provides.  The hint text for that says:

> The link column is included as the first column in the report and
>   cannot be hidden by the user. The link column can navigate to either a
>   single row detail view of the selected row, another page within the
>   application or the provided URL.

So it would appear you cannot change its position - except perhaps by writing some nifty Javascript that modifies the DOM.

You don't have to use the APEX built-in Link Column though, you could just add an extra column to the query and use the Link properties of the report column to make it into a link.  This would then be movable like all the other columns.

Comment: Problem is that Link Column is not standart column. Look at picture - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27452391/apex.png